# Release upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 display not running with systemd. Upstart - no problem

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, lightdm, systemd, gdm

I had **14.04** until two days ago. Finally decided to do **release upgrade** to **16.04** and here we go - I ended up with missing display environment when starting with **systemd**. Good thing is that using **upstart** everything works fine.

It was saying: **error opening display**

I suspect two things in my configuration:

1. My video card and driver? I am using: **GeForce GT 630** with  **NVIDIA Driver Version: 375.66** from the official nvidia web.
2. I have installed Mac theme from here:

http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html

No matter what i do if I switch to anything different then **lightdm** - it never runs, not even with upstart. I tried with **lightDM** and **gdm3** - no luck at all. lightdm at least brings me to command line login, the other freezes at ubuntu loading dots (dots are moving but that's all).

Last two days I spent a lot of time trying to make this work, with no success at all. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time reading this!

Comment: in those two days you could have copied your home to another drive or removable drive reinstalled with a live USB and reconfigured to your licking and finalized with non-home app instalations with probably alot of time to spare. :-) anyways have you tried unistalling nvidia driver and installing nvidia driver following this guide : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus?  After this rerun updates and see if you need to install manually some core ubuntu packages that failed to install. tell me if this helps.

Comment: I did this Nvidia driver thing already. Just to make sure - I did it again now too... With systemd I got ubuntu loading logo and then 5 cool red dots hanging on my screen. That's all. Sorry.

Comment: after the five dots could you do `ctrl`-`alt`-`F5` ? if that works login and see what you can run from there? or is that already what you're doing?

Comment: [screenshot](https://createeasyreview.com/IMG_0489.JPG)
Not sure what else to try. Not that good with linux..

Comment: ok so i imagine that's what you were already doing. does `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` work?  if yes if you haven't already, run the commands from the guide I linked to install the correct nvidia drive then also try these for kicks `sudo apt-get install unity unity-scope-askubuntu unity-lens-applications unity-webapps-bbcnews unity-greeter ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends indicator-applet-complete`

Comment: Finally resolved. I've noticed I always had  read only environment on systemd startup. It turns out that my fstab primary disk UUID was somehow messed up - interesting upstart had no problem with this..nor I had any troubles before upgrading from 14.04. So i placed to correct UUID and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am placing the answer here in case anyone has the same problem:

Finally resolved. I've noticed **I always had read only file system** after systemd startup. It turns out that **my fstab primary disk UUID was somehow messed up** - interesting upstart had no problem with this..nor I had any troubles before upgrading from 14.04. So **I just replaced it with the  correct UUID** and now it works just fine.