# KDE 17.04 is crashing too much

Tags: keyboard, mouse, kde

I am having an issue wich my KDE 17.04. It crashes very often and I don't know why. within few hours today, it has crashed two times. Sometimes keyboard works but the mouse does not, and sometimes nothing works, no keyboard, no mouse. Is someone having the same issue? do you have any idea on how to solve or where to start checking?

**Update**
Apart from the fact that it crashes from time to time, everything works well

result of `sudo dmidecode`

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.
71 structures occupying 3613 bytes.
Table at 0x000E6DC0.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: LENOVO
        Version: C6CN34WW
        Release Date: 10/29/2015
        Address: 0xE0000
        Runtime Size: 128 kB
        ROM Size: 6144 kB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.34
        Firmware Revision: 0.31

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information                                                                                                                                                                                    
        Manufacturer: LENOVO                                                                                                                                                                          
        Product Name: 80MK                                                                                                                                                                            
        Version: Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK                                                                                                                                                                
        Serial Number: PF0EG211                                                                                                                                                                       
        UUID: ADAC1DA0-7872-11E5-BA4C-507B9D556713                                                                                                                                                    
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch                                                                                                                                                                    
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80MK_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK                                                                                                                                   
        Family: IDEAPAD                                                                                                                                                                               

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes                                                                                                                                                                   
Base Board Information                                                                                                                                                                                
        Manufacturer: LENOVO                                                                                                                                                                          
        Product Name: VIUU4
        Version: SDK0J40709 WIN
        Serial Number: PF0EG211
        Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Type: Notebook
        Lock: Not Present
        Version: Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK
        Serial Number: PF0EG211
        Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
        Boot-up State: Safe
        Power Supply State: Safe
        Thermal State: Safe
        Security Status: None
        OEM Information: 0x00000000
        Height: Unspecified
        Number Of Power Cords: 1
        Contained Elements: 0
        SKU Number: SKU Number

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: U3E1
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Core i7
        Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
        ID: E3 06 04 00 FF FB EB BF
        Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 78, Stepping 3
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                VME (Virtual mode extension)
                DE (Debugging extension)
                PSE (Page size extension)
                TSC (Time stamp counter)
                MSR (Model specific registers)
                PAE (Physical address extension)
                MCE (Machine check exception)
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                SEP (Fast system call)
                MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                PGE (Page global enable)
                MCA (Machine check architecture)
                CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
                PAT (Page attribute table)
                PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
                CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
                DS (Debug store)
                ACPI (ACPI supported)
                MMX (MMX technology supported)
                FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
                SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
                SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
                SS (Self-snoop)
                HTT (Multi-threading)
                TM (Thermal monitor supported)
                PBE (Pending break enabled)
        Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
        Voltage: 1.0 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 2600 MHz
        Current Speed: 3000 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Socket BGA1168
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x0006
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x0007
        L3 Cache Handle: 0x0008
        Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Core Count: 2
        Core Enabled: 2
        Thread Count: 4
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable
                Multi-Core
                Hardware Thread
                Execute Protection
                Enhanced Virtualization
                Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L1 Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 64 kB
        Maximum Size: 64 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Synchronous
        Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Error Correction Type: Parity
        System Type: Data
        Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L1 Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 64 kB
        Maximum Size: 64 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Synchronous
        Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Error Correction Type: Parity
        System Type: Instruction
        Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L2 Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 512 kB
        Maximum Size: 512 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Synchronous
        Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: L3 Cache
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 4096 kB
        Maximum Size: 4096 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Synchronous
        Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Keyboard
        External Connector Type: PS/2
        Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Mouse
        External Connector Type: PS/2
        Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: TV OUT
        External Connector Type: Mini DIN
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: CRT
        External Connector Type: DB-15 female
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: COM 1
        External Connector Type: DB-9 male
        Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J5A2
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Network
        External Connector Type: RJ-45
        Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J9G2
        Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
        External Reference Designator: OnBoard Floppy Type
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J7J1
        Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
        External Reference Designator: OnBoard Primary IDE
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J30
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Microphone In
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J30
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Line In
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J30
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Speaker Out
        External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J6C1
        Type: x1 PCI Express x1
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Other
        ID: 1
        Characteristics:
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.0

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J6D2
        Type: x1 PCI Express x1
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Other
        ID: 2
        Characteristics:
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.1

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J7C1
        Type: x1 PCI Express x1
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Other
        ID: 3
        Characteristics:
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.2

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J7D1
        Type: x1 PCI Express x1
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Other
        ID: 4
        Characteristics:
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: J8C1
        Type: x4 PCI Express x4
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Other
        ID: 5
        Characteristics:
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.4

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
        String 1: OemString1
        String 2: OemString2
        String 3: OemString3

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
        Option 1: ConfigOptions1
        Option 2: ConfigOptions2
        Option 3: ConfigOptions3

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
        Language Description Format: Long
        Installable Languages: 8
                en|US|iso8859-1,0
                fr|CA|iso8859-1,0
                zh|TW|unicode,0
                ja|JP|unicode,0
                it|IT|iso8859-1,0
                es|ES|iso8859-1,0
                de|DE|iso8859-1,0
                pt|PT|iso8859-1,0
        Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1,0

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 14, 17 bytes
Group Associations
        Name: Firmware Version Info
        Items: 4
                0x0040 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
                0x003B (<OUT OF SPEC>)
                0x003A (<OUT OF SPEC>)
                0x0039 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 14, 8 bytes
Group Associations
        Name: Intel(R) Silicon View Technology
        Items: 1
                0x0044 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 14, 8 bytes
Group Associations
        Name: $MEI
        Items: 1
                0x003F (<OUT OF SPEC>)


Handle 0x002D, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 8 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x0028
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x002B
        Partition Row Position: Unknown
        Interleave Position: 2
        Interleaved Data Depth: 1

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
Built-in Pointing Device
        Type: Touch Pad
        Interface: PS/2
        Buttons: 4

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
        Location: Fake
        Manufacturer: -Virtual Battery 0-
        Manufacture Date: 08/08/2010
        Serial Number: Battery 0
        Name: CRB Battery 0
        Chemistry: Zinc Air
        Design Capacity: Unknown
        Design Voltage: Unknown
        SBDS Version: Not Specified
        Maximum Error: Unknown
        OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
        Power-On Password Status: Disabled
        Keyboard Password Status: Disabled
        Administrator Password Status: Disabled
        Front Panel Reset Status: Disabled

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 26, 24 bytes
Voltage Probe
        Description: Voltage Probe Description
        Location: Unknown
        Status: Unknown
        Maximum Value: Unknown
        Minimum Value: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown
        Tolerance: Unknown
        Accuracy: Unknown
        OEM-specific Information: 0x00008000
        Nominal Value: 0.000 V

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 27, 15 bytes
Cooling Device
        Temperature Probe Handle: 0x0033
        Type: Fan
        Status: OK
        OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
        Nominal Speed: 8192 rpm
        Description: Cooling Device Description

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 28, 24 bytes
Temperature Probe
        Description: Temperature Probe Description
        Location: Unknown
        Status: Unknown
        Maximum Value: Unknown
        Minimum Value: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown
        Tolerance: Unknown
        Accuracy: Unknown
        OEM-specific Information: 0x00008000
        Nominal Value: 0.0 deg C

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 32, 11 bytes
System Boot Information
        Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
System Power Supply
        Location: OEM Define 0
        Name: OEM Define 1
        Manufacturer: OEM Define 2
        Serial Number: OEM Define 3
        Asset Tag: OEM Define 4
        Model Part Number: OEM Define 5
        Revision: OEM Define 6
        Max Power Capacity: 75 W
        Status: Not Present
        Type: Regulator
        Input Voltage Range Switching: Auto-switch
        Plugged: No
        Hot Replaceable: No

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 40, 17 bytes
Additional Information 1
        Referenced Handle: 0x000e
        Referenced Offset: 0x05
        String: PCIExpressx16
        Value: 0xaa
Additional Information 2
        Referenced Handle: 0x0000
        Referenced Offset: 0x05
        String: Compiler Version: VC 9.0
        Value: 0x00

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
        Reference Designation: IGD
        Type: Video
        Status: Disabled
        Type Instance: 1
        Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 128, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                80 08 38 00 55 AA 55 AA
        Strings:
                Oem Type 128 Test 1
                Oem Type 128 Test 2

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 129, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                81 08 39 00 01 01 02 01
        Strings:
                Insyde_ASF_001
                Insyde_ASF_002

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 130, 20 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                82 14 3A 00 24 41 4D 54 01 01 01 01 01 A5 1F 02
                00 00 00 00



Handle 0x003C, DMI type 133, 5 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                85 05 3C 00 01
        Strings:
                KHOIHGIUCCHHII

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                88 06 3D 00 FF FF

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 200, 16 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                C8 10 3E 00 01 02 01 22 01 12 01 3D B2 80 01 05
        Strings:
                IdeaPad
                80MK005TMZ

Handle 0x003F, DMI type 219, 81 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DB 51 3F 00 01 03 01 55 02 00 A0 06 01 00 60 00
                00 00 00 00 40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00
        Strings:
                MEI1
                MEI2
                MEI3

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DD 1A 40 00 03 01 00 01 04 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
                00 33 00 03 00 00 05 00 00 00
        Strings:
                Reference Code - CPU
                uCode Version
                TXT ACM version

Handle 0x0041, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DD 1A 41 00 03 01 00 01 04 00 00 00 02 00 01 04
                00 00 00 03 04 0B 00 00 90 04
        Strings:
                Reference Code - ME 11.0
                MEBx version
                ME Firmware Version
                Consumer SKU


Handle 0x0044, DMI type 222, 14 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DE 0E 44 00 01 99 00 03 10 01 20 02 30 03
        Strings:
                Memory Init Complete
                End of DXE Phase
                BIOS Boot Complete

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 248, 18 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                F8 12 45 00 AC AC AA 17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00

Handle 0xFEFF, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: wow that is vague. no there aren't that many people who have your issue probably noone else but you. but i can't tell you what you have unless you give some info. your text could do with a bit of formatting and some grammar it really is to the point where I (and the community here) can't undestand what you're saying. "something nothing"? did you mean stometimes nothing? "nothing" might imply the pc does not even turn on, I'm guessing that's not the case? next step BIOS? next step GRUB? next step login screen? next step desktop? if you're on the desktop that rules out alot. tell us more.

Comment: @tatsu sorry for grammar, I still learning English so sometimes a make mistakes.

Comment: I still really can't help you with that much info. Can you copy this : `sudo dmidecode,` type: `ctr`-`alt`-`T`,  in the window that opens do `ctrl`-`shift`-`V` and enter (your then have to type in your password and enter), now select the whole output do `ctrl`-`shift`-`C`  come back here edit your post and `ctrl`-`V` the result into your post select it and click the "code" icon in our editor this way it is correctly formatted and can be read by us. I'll need a couple more commands after this but first this one.

Comment: @tatsu it was too long So I had to remove some lines. If you need something else, just tell me

Comment: did you ever have windows installed on this machine and if yes did it crash too? also take a photo of the screen next time it crashes and add it to your post and also try (when it crashes) type `ctrl-alt-F1` does anything happen? ( a black screen  waiting for you to login?)

Comment: @tatsu I have never really used Windows on my laptop. But I think it has to do with Kubuntu 17.04 since Kubuntu 16.04 worked pretty well.

Comment: good enough. did you upgrade or install the new 17.04 via live usb? try the two other things i asked in my post above please. :-)

Comment: @tatsu I will try the next time it crashes.  No, I did not upgrade to 17.04  through USB. I have upgraded online with a command line(I don't remember de exact command).

Comment: yup that's the issue. I'd recommend never ever doing that again. copy your `home` to another hard drive and create an install USB using the preinstalled `Startup Disk Creator` app and once install is complete move the content of your home back.

Answer (score 0):

So following our conversation it's an upgrade to 17.04 issue which there are too many of and the symptoms vary too much with no 100% fix for any of them other than to reinstall. Sorry.

Go ahead and follow my guide here : 
 [The system freezes in the log-in sceen after an OS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914208/the-system-freezes-in-the-log-in-sceen-after-an-os-upgrade/914480#914480)

I recommend using the "format/erase disk and install kubuntu" option or the "something else option" you don't want it trying to use the old grub .